# Can't override magento 1 controller method

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, controllers

I am trying to override community controller(which is overriding core controller) but Its not overriding...
Local module files

```
<modules>
    <WoofDigital_Enquiry>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <JakeSharp_Waterlee/>
        </depends>
    </WoofDigital_Enquiry>
</modules>
```

**config.xml**

```
<fronend>
        <routers>
            <jakesharp_waterlee_contacts>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <WoofDigital_Enquiry before="JakeSharp_Waterlee">WoofDigital_Enquiry</WoofDigital_Enquiry>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </jakesharp_waterlee_contacts>
        </routers>
    </fronend>
```

**controllers/Contacts/IndexController.php**

```
require_once 'JakeSharp/Waterlee/controllers/Contacts/IndexController.php';
class WoofDigital_Enquiry_Contacts_IndexController extends JakeSharp_Waterlee_Contacts_IndexController
{
    public function postAction()
    {
        die('Controller override');
    }
}
```

**Community config.xml**

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <contacts>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <jakesharp_waterlee_contacts before="Mage_Contacts">JakeSharp_Waterlee_Contacts</jakesharp_waterlee_contacts>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </contacts>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

**community Controller**

```
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Contacts').DS.'IndexController.php');

class JakeSharp_Waterlee_Contacts_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
```

Anyone who can just put me in right direction because I think I am doing everything right as it required by Magento 1.9.3
Thanks

Comment: There is a typo mistake in your **config.xml**. Use `<frontend>` instead of `<fronend>`

Comment: check error log after trying below solution if it will not solve your issue

Comment: Its not showing anything in error log, because its going in community controller rather than local controller.

Answer (score 3):

In your module's `config.xml`

try this-

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <contacts>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <WoofDigital_Enquiry before="JakeSharp_Waterlee">WoofDigital_Enquiry</WoofDigital_Enquiry>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
```

Instead of

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <jakesharp_waterlee_contacts>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <WoofDigital_Enquiry before="JakeSharp_Waterlee">WoofDigital_Enquiry</WoofDigital_Enquiry>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </jakesharp_waterlee_contacts>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
```

Comment: does not work... still going in community controller